# Is my wireless router throttling?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, firewall, pfsense

I've got a cable modem (wan) --> dell laptop (lan with pfsense installed) --> wireless router (opt1, bridged). When pinging from the laptop I am getting:

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=0 ttl=57 time=17.110 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=16.417 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=14.703 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 14.703/16.077/17.110/1.012 ms
```

But when I ping from the wireless router, I am getting:

```
Pinging 8.8.8.8 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=46ms TTL=56
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=56
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=392ms TTL=56
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=56

Ping statistics for 8.8.8.8:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 16ms, Maximum = 392ms, Average = 120ms
```

The internet is extremely slow from the wireless router, while when connected with a cable directly into pfsense laptop, I am getting like 30mbps.

Apologies that I cannot paste the images inline because I do not have a high enough rating, but here are the settings of my wireless router:

[image]

Here are the details on my pfsense settings:

```
wan:1000baseT <full-duplex,master>
lan:100baseTX <full-duplex>
opt1:autoselect
```

[image]

Also, I do not know why, but it is blocking a ton of ipv6 traffic:

[image]

dhcp service log entries:

[image]

WAN firewall rules:

[image]

LAN firewall rules:

[image]

wireless router (opt1) firewall rules:

[image]

**How do I remove the throttling from the wireless router?**

Comment: You haven't found the root cause of the slowness yet. You have a theory of "throttling", but no evidence that it's throttling as opposed to overloaded or underpowered or buggy or having a failing Ethernet cable. Once you identify the root cause, how to mitigate it will be easier to answer.

Comment: indeed, i need help identifying the cause.

Comment: Yes indeed the modem is in bridge mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as Spiff suggested, you need to find the root cause.  Look into the OSI model for advise on how to troubleshoot :

[OSI Troubleshooting](http://www.pearsonitcertification.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1730891)

The first thing you want to do is check your physical connections- even if the cable APPEARS good, that is not always true, a swapoit is an easy troubleshooting step.

In your router you are having ipv6 blocked.  Try disabling ipv6, and run a speedtest, and compare to it enabled.  Maybe something on your network is bottling through its ipv6 traffic.

Last but not least, borrow a friends router and set it up with your modem.  compare its results with your routers.

One other thing you can do if you are comfortable with command line, ping the wireless router while NOTHING is connected to it wirelessly, and ONLY your pc is connected - use ping (router ip) -t for continuous output.  Look for unusual spikes in ping, or unresponiveness for clues to the router being defective.  Do the same test wirelessly with you as the only client- but wireless is trickier because you have more factors for faults, such as outside interference...

Comment: steven thank you very much for this insightful answer.

Comment: firmware upgrade has resolved the issue!!!!!!!